# Flatten jsonb as columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table in PostgreSQL 10.6 that looks more or less like this:

```
Name             │  Description        │ Data
─────────────────┼─────────────────────┼──────────────────────
Jhon             │ A guy               │ {"age": 23, "food": "Burger"}
Carl             │ Another guy         │ {"age": 35, "food": "Pizza"}
Josh             │ Again               │ {"age": 27, "food": "Burrito", "id": 3}
```

I would like to have a query that includes the information in the jsonb flattened. 
Where **every key is a new column** with it's value. \

Usually all the JSONs have the same keys but could be that they have on extra key in the future, in which case showing it as `NULL` or not showing it at all is fine.

So the result should be something like

```
Name   │  Description │ Age │ Food  │ Id
───────┼──────────────┼─────┼─────-─┼──────
Jhon   │ A guy        │ 23  │Burger │ NULL
Carl   │ Another guy  │ 35  │Pizza  │ NULL
Josh   │ Again        │ 27  │Burrito│ 3
```

Comment: I have seen there is the [jsonb_populate_record](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-json.html) but not sure how can be used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done creating a type and with [jsonb_populate_record](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-json.html)

```
CREATE TYPE user_data AS (age int, food text, id int);

SELECT users.name, user.description, flatten.* 
FROM users, jsonb_populate_record(null::user_data, data) as flatten
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `->>` [operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html):

```
select name, 
       description,
       (data ->> 'age')::int as age,
       data ->> 'food' as food,
       data ->> 'id' as id
from the_table
```

Comment: The data has multiple keys and have to be used in many places, I don't want to use the accessor

Comment: @CristianRiaño: then create a view with that select. But there is no way to do this without explicitly listing all output columns in some way.

Comment: Yes it can be done. Please don't assure things you don't know @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: @CristianRiaño: you are still explicitly defining the output columns with the user type. Just at a different place.